# neo4j: REST API call to get the whole connected subgraph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Build a D3 viewer, I'd like to get all the nodes connected to one, and all the links connecting these nodes. In fact, the same thing as in the default neo4j viewer....

For example, I have

```
CREATE (a:Person {name:'a'})
CREATE (b:Person {name:'b'})
CREATE (c:Person {name:'c'})
CREATE (d:Person {name:'d'})
CREATE (a)-[:KNOWS]->(b)
CREATE (a)-[:KNOWS]->(c)
CREATE (b)-[:KNOWS]->(c)
CREATE (c)-[:KNOWS]->(d)
```

I can issue some ugly cypher query to give to the POST call, but it does not scale with medium size graphs (~100k nodes, 3M relationships).

Looking, at the posted queries in the neo4j browser, it looks like there are 2 successive one:

A) get the connected nodes

```
MATCH (p:Person {name:'a'})-[l:KNOWS]-(q:Person) RETURN p,q
```

B) get the links existing between these nodes

```
"START a = node(185282,185283,185284), b = node(185282,185283,185284)
 MATCH a -[r]-> b
 RETURN r;"
```

My two questions:

1. Is there a clean way to get list of unique nodes?
2. Is this two steps method the preferred one?

Again, the data can be a bit heavy, so let's keep that in mind

Thanks for the help

Alex

Comment: Please specify how those nodes are connected and which connections you want to retrieve. You've put two queries in your question which does not seem to be related to each other. Either use the same node names or show which id's are returned by first query and used in the second. The query I've provided below answers your `get all the nodes connected to one, and all the links connecting these nodes` requirement. If you did not get the results you expected please ask a precise question.

Comment: He. Sorry if if was not clear enough. I'm looking for retrieving A-B, A-C, but also B-C. That would be the nodes connected to A and their interconnecting links. In the same way the neo4j browser does it, when it it in graph mode, not in row mode.
Is that more clear? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the results of the first query to the second one [using `WITH`](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-with.html) to get all connections between Persons which the 'a' Person knows:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[l:KNOWS]-(q:Person)
WHERE p.name = "a"
WITH p,q
MATCH (p)-[r]-(q)
RETURN p,r,q
```

Comment: Hi Maciej. Thanks for the answer, but that does not look to give me the relation b-c, which would be the graph of the nodes connected to a.

Comment: Just by curiosity, it might be obvious but what is the difference between your query and 
MATCH (p:Person {name:'a'})-[l:KNOWS]-(q:Person) RETURN p,l,q
Is there any hidden performance tricks?

Comment: The difference is that my query will return all relationships between two persons that know each other, not only the `KNOWS`. So for example `LIKES`, `IS_MARRIED_TO` etc.

Comment: thanks. That makes sense. and it makes sense my question was not clear ;)

Comment: Yw. Sorry I can't help you further. After you clarified the question your intent become obvious but I just don't know if it is possible to do in one query. I'm pretty sure that it isn't, but I might be wrong. I've check the logs looking for clues on how the browser application does it, and it turns out that it also uses two separate queries, exactly like the ones you provided. So it might be better to get used to this.